# Best way of sanitize unparametrizable sql

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, sql-injection

I have to make a SQL string to be injected in a database for a third party to read it, execute it, and making a report with the results. Since the user can choose the columns wanted for the report, as well as renaming the columns, I've ended with a code like this:

```
string sql = "SELECT ";
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> field in report.fields)
{
    sql += "[" + field.Key + "] as [" + field.Value + "];
}
sql += " WHERE idrpt=@id";
```

The only part of this query I can parametrize is the WHERE clause, but if my research on the web has'nt been misguided, there's no way to parametrize the column names and aliases in the SELECT clause. Now, given that I can't change the way the program works (I have to produce a valid SQL query to a third party to execute it), what would be the best way of sanitize the input string?

I've solved the part about column names by checking them against a list of valid columns, but I can't do that for the aliases, which can be whatever string of less than 80 characters the user is willing to give.

Comment: This is a big of an X/Y question. One answer is don't do this and change your program design to not need this.

Comment: Another way would be to only allow alphanumeric ascii characters and a designated whitespace and then to also escape the string

Comment: You've missed the part about "I can't change the way the program works". That makes your comment a big of an XY rant. The second comment, by the way, is more of a solution... I could limit the valid characters on the name aliases against a regular expression. I'll give it a thought.

Comment: I don't see how someone could reasonably carry a SQL injection using only alphanumeric chars and a whitespace, so that would probably protect against that. This has the advantage of making sense as limitation for column names and aliases too.

Comment: Sure, but while most of our customers speack spanish, some use english, french or catalan and so I can't rule out single quotes (apostrophes) in the text. I suppose I can allow only alphanumeric characters and single quotes, then sanitizing for single quotes only.

Comment: Usually common wisdom is that you can't rely on either sanitizing or escaping and that any situation in which you'd need to is a design error, but that doesn't help you there. So yeah, escaping single quotes specifically and otherwise only allowing alphanumeric characters would probably work for you. Do you want me to write this up as an answer or do you want to self-answer?

Comment: Write it as an answer and I probably will accept it, since as you say I don't see any other way to get out of this mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so you have a SQL layout you can't change that necessitates you to do this. That is unfortunate, but lets make the best of it.

As you stated in your comments, you probably need *some* special character support, so specifically escape these special characters.

Other then that, you should reduce the allowed names to alphanumeric characters and possibly whitespace. Validate these against your validation mechanism of choice, for instance regex, and allow only those characters. That will probably keep you mostly safe from SQL injection.

This isn't optimal, but it seems to be the best you can do in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted there is no way to parametrize the column names and aliases. Therefore, you are opened to SQL injection. To minimize the issue you can use [quotename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql), which is similar to the approach you are using currently.

```
string sql = "SELECT ";
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> field in report.fields)
{
  sql += "quotename(" + field.Key + ") as quotename(" + field.Value + ")";
}
sql += " WHERE idrpt=@id";
```

Comment: Yes, that's the current approach I'm using right now. In fact, I'm using QUOTENAME(" + field.Value.Replace("'", "''") + ")", but I'm still unsure about it.